# Fastest way to insert/update a million rows in Laravel 5.7

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using Laravel 5.7 to fetch large amounts of data (around 500k rows) from an API server and insert it into a table (call it Table A) quite frequently (at least every six hours, 24/7) - however, it's enough to insert only the changes the next time we insert (but at least 60-70% of the items will change). So this table will quickly have tens of millions of rows.

I came up with the idea to make a helper table (call it Table B) to store all the new data into it. Before inserting everything into Table A, I want to compare it to the previous data (with Laravel, PHP) from Table B - so I will only insert the records that need to be updated. Again it will usually be around 60-70% of the records.

**My first question** is if this above-mentioned way is the preferred way of doing it, in this situation (obviously I want to make it happen as fast as possible.) I assume that searching for an updating the records in the table would take a lot more time and it would keep the table busy / lock it. Is there a better way to achieve the same (meaning to update the records in the DB).

---

The second issue I'm facing is the slow insert times. Right now I'm using a local environment (16GB RAM, I7-6920HQ CPU) and MySQL is inserting the rows very slowly (about 30-40 records at a time). The size of one row is around 50 bytes.

I know it can be made a lot faster by fiddling around with InnoDB's settings. However, I'd also like to think that I can do something on Laravel's side to improve performance.

Right now my Laravel code looks like this (only inserting 1 record at a time):

```
foreach ($response as $key => $value)
{
    DB::table('table_a')
        ->insert(
        [
            'test1' => $value['test1'],
            'test2' => $value['test2'],
            'test3' => $value['test3'],
            'test4' => $value['test4'],
            'test5' => $value['test5'],
        ]);
}
```

`$response` is a type of array.

**So my second question:** is there any way to increase the inserting time of the records to something like 50k/second - both on the Laravel application layer (by doing batch inserts) and MySQL InnoDB level (changing the config).

Current InnoDB settings:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size        = 256M
innodb_log_file_size           = 256M
innodb_thread_concurrency      = 16
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_flush_method            = normal
innodb_use_native_aio = true
```

MySQL version is 5.7.21.

If I forgot to tell/add anything, please let me know in a comment and I will do it quickly.

**Edit 1:**
The server that I'm planning to use will have SSD on it - if that makes any difference. I assume MySQL inserts will still count as I/O.

Comment: InnoDB writes every INSERT to the disk directly which cause disk i/o,, You might gain more performance starting a transaction and committing every 1000 or 2000 inserts.

Comment: Might be helpful https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#chunking-results

Comment: Do you use any ssd on your server?

Comment: innodb_buffer_pool_size of 256M is exceptionally small for a 16G server - start at 8G if available. Doing bulk insertions means that innodb_log_file_size might be too small too. innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit of 2 is sacrificing your data safety for import speed globally. Once you batch up the inserts this shouldn't be an issue and innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  can be set back to 1. A secondary table isn't gaining you much AFAIK.

Answer (score 10):

## Disable `autocommit` and manually commit at end of insertion

According to MySQL 8.0 docs. ([8.5.5 Bulk Data Loading for InnoDB Tables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html))

You can increase the INSERT speed by turning off auto commit:

> - When importing data into InnoDB, turn off autocommit mode, because it performs a log flush to disk for every insert. To disable autocommit during your import operation, surround it with SET autocommit and COMMIT statements:
>
> ```
>     SET autocommit=0;
>     ... SQL import statements ...
>     COMMIT;
> ```

Other way to do it in Laravel is using [Database Transactions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database#database-transactions):

```
DB::beginTransaction()

// Your inserts here

DB::commit()
```

## Use `INSERT` with multiple `VALUES`

Also according to MySQL 8.0 docs ([8.2.5.1 Optimizing INSERT Statements](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-optimization.html)) you can optimize INSERT speed by using multiple `VALUES` on a single insert statement.

To do it with Laravel, you can just pass an array of values to the `insert()` method:

```
DB::table('your_table')->insert([
   [
       'column_a'=>'value',
       'column_b'=>'value',
   ],
   [
       'column_a'=>'value',
       'column_b'=>'value',
   ],
   [
       'column_a'=>'value',
       'column_b'=>'value',
   ],
]);
```

According to the docs, it can be many times faster.

## Read the docs

Both MySQL docs links that I put on this post have tons of tips on increasing INSERT speed.

## Avoid using Laravel/PHP for inserting it

If your data source is (or can be) a CSV file, you can run it a lot faster using [`mysqlimport`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqlimport.html) to import the data.

Using PHP and Laravel to import data from a CSV file is an overhead, unless you need to do some data processing before inserting.

Answer (score 6):

Don't call `insert()` inside a `foreach()` because it will execute `n number of queries` to the database when you have `n number of data`.

First create an array of data objects matching with the database column names.  and then pass the created array to `insert()` function.

This will only execute `one` query to the database regardless of how many number of data you have.

This is way faster, way too faster.

```
$data_to_insert = [];

foreach ($response as $key => $value)
{
    array_push($data_to_insert, [
            'test1' => $value['test1'],
            'test2' => $value['test2'],
            'test3' => $value['test3'],
            'test4' => $value['test4'],
            'test5' => $value['test5'],
    ]);
}

DB::table('table_a')->insert($data_to_insert);
```

Comment: Doing that with 500k rows could be challenging though. I'd recommend chunking the insert.

Comment: @Namoshek Agreed

Comment: chunking results and using an eloquent collection could be helpful too: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/collections#method-chunk

Answer (score 6):

Thanks @Namoshek, I had also the same problem. solution is like this.

```
$users= array_chunk($data, 500, true);

foreach ($users as $key => $user) {
  Model::insert($user);
}
```

Depends on data, you can also make use of array_push() and then insert.

Answer (score 2):

You need to do multiple row insert but also chunk your insert to not exceed your DB limits

You can do this by chunking your array

```php
foreach (array_chunk($response, 1000) as $responseChunk)
{
    $insertableArray = [];
    foreach($responseChunk as $value) {
        $insertableArray[] = [
            'test1' => $value['test1'],
            'test2' => $value['test2'],
            'test3' => $value['test3'],
            'test4' => $value['test4'],
            'test5' => $value['test5'],
        ];
    }
    DB::table('table_a')->insert($insertableArray);
}
```

You can increase the  size of the chunk `1000` till you approach you DB configuration limit. Make sure to leave some security margin (0.6 times your DB limit).

You can't go any faster than this using laravel.

Answer (score 0):

I usually handle this problem using pagination, jobs and functions are executed recursively, all looping processes per each page are carried out in a separate job recursively.

```
class ProcessPurchaseJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $page;

    public function __construct($page = null)
    {
        $this->page = $page ?? 1;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        $batchSize = 1000; // Amount of data per page

        $purchases = Purchase::orderBy('id')
            ->paginate($batchSize, ['*'], 'page', $this->page);

        foreach ($purchases as $item) {
            // Execute your purchase logic code
        }

        // If there are still next pages, call the job again recursively
        if ($users->hasMorePages()) {
            dispatch(new ProcessPurchaseJob($users->currentPage() + 1));
        }
    }
}
```

Then call the job anywhere

```
ProcessPurchaseJob::dispatch();
```