# Troubles using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE to store CSV data into MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

**UPDATE:**

As per the answer suggesting the use of `Table::insert`, I updated the query.

```
// At this point the data is stored in an array
// I turn it into a collection to make use of the chunk function
$records = collect($records); 
// I split the array into chunks
// Inserting everything at once gave memory issues
$chunks = $records->chunk(500); 
// Then I iterate the chunks and insert them into the database
foreach ($chunks as $chunk) {
    \DB::table('table')->insert($chunk->toArray()); 
}
```

The issue with this is that while being faster than using the previous method, it still takes several minutes to insert everything into my database, so it's not an actual solution.

I'm not sure if this is the wrong approach, if I'm missing something/doing something wrong here.

---

**Description:**

I have an Angular form where the user can upload a .txt file containing CSV data. This is how it works:

HTML:

```
  <input type="file" class="form-control w-auto" (change)="getFile($event)" accept=".txt" />
```

Typescript:

```
  getFile(e) {
    this.file = e.target.files[0];
    this.file_description = e.target.files[0].name;
  }

  submit() {
    let reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = () => {
      let result = reader.result;
      this.ImportService.import(result).subscribe(
        (response) => {
          // Do success stuff
        },
        (_error) => {
          // Do error stuff
        }
      );
    };

    if (this.file) {
      reader.readAsText(this.file, "UTF-16LE");
    }
  }
```

This sends the data to my Laravel instance, where I want to store it into MySQL.
I've been able to do this by processing the received data into an array and inserting each row one by one, like this:

PHP:

```
$array = array();
$csv = str_getcsv($request->file, "\n");
foreach ($csv as &$row) {
    $row = str_getcsv($row, ";");
    $array[] = $row;
}
array_splice($array, 0, 1);

foreach ($array as &$row) {
    $query = Table::firstOrNew(['col2' => $row[1], 'col3' => $row[2]]);
    $query->col1 = $row[0];
    $query->col2 = $row[1];
    $query->col3 = $row[2];
    $query->col4 = $row[3];
    $query->col5 = $row[4];
    // [...]
    $query->col72 = $row[71];
    $query->col73 = $row[72];
    $query->save();
}
```

---

**The Problem:**

The data being sent here contains around 100.000 records. This method is way too slow, often leading to timeouts/5-10+ minutes of waiting.

---

**Attempted Solution:**

I've been trying to use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE`, but I can't get it to work.

Here's the code:

```
$results = DB::connection()->getpdo()->exec(
    "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '" . $request->file . "' IGNORE INTO TABLE `table`
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';'
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
    IGNORE 1 LINES (
        `col1`,
        `col2`,
        `col3`,
        // etc
    )"
);
```

In short, there are three issues with this method:

- If the CSV data contains any Apostrophes I get a syntax error.
- The `local_infile` property on my MySQL instance is disabled by default, and reverts to disable on restart.
- With the above fixed, I get the following error: `General error: 7890 Can't find file 'col1;col2;col3;etc'`.

I've tried using `LOAD DATA INFILE` but I'm getting several 'access denied' errors when the query tries to fetch the file contents.

---

If you need any further information pleases let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Tasks like this are probably better suited to be handled in a [Queue/Job](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues) so that the user isn't waiting for this to complete in real time.

Either way, I would recommend refactoring the code though. firstOrNew() will run queries for every single record you process, so it will be a major strain on the database.

The methods insert() and update() support processing many records at a time, so use PHP to preprocess the records so you can utilize those two methods.

Use one database query to get all the existing records and then build two arrays to call insert() and update().

I think you can create a where query like this if you create pairs of values that you want to search on:

```
Table::where(function($query) use ($pairs) {
    foreach ($pairs as $pair) {
        $query->where('col2', $pair['col2'])->where('col3', $pair['col3']);
    }
});
```

That will give you the existing records, so then you can loop through all records in PHP to build your two arrays and then run the insert and update queries only one time:

```
Table::insert($new_records);
Table::update($existing_records);
```

Comment: This seems to work great when testing with a few rows, but when trying to insert the entire dataset after creating the array it returns a 500 error after about 20-30 seconds of processing with no specific information. The issue seems to be the insert statement as removing it returns success. Is there a way to debug this properly?

Comment: If there's nothing in the log from the 500 error, it might a memory issue. Try to increase the limit in your php.ini. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58629022/3103434) might help too.

Comment: Sorry for the late answer @Spudly, came across two issues and had to dig deeper into debugging and getting it sorted. I applied this method and it seems to work, but it still takes a long time to complete. I had to split the dataset into chunks to avoid memory issues (which was the issue of my previous comment), and while it's still faster than using `firstOrNew()` it's still less than ideal. Not sure if I'm doing something wrong, taking the wrong approach or missing something here. Updated the OP with more information.

Comment: @Kurisu It is going to take some time to process a large amount of data like this. You can increase the memory limit and chunk size to see if that helps, but it's probably better to run this in the background using Laravel's Queue or another Job based approach so that you can do this processing without making the user wait for it to complete.